# jquery.form.js with option iframeTarget (works fine for FF, does not work in IE)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, multifile-uploader

i need a interface to upload multiple file to a DMS, where i can not modify the Result Page.

I have a solution with jquery.form.js (without using iframeTarget), which works fine for FF but does not work for IE: In IE i got the first file uploaded, but after this, the Page is redirected and the second upload does not work.

I think, the main Problem is, that the Resulting Page does a redirect, which i expect inside the IFrame (for FF) but on the page (for IE).

With Firebug i see, that the result of the Post contains such a redirect, wich is "ignored" by FF and so the following files are uploaded.

To get closer to the Problem it tried to use the option iframeTarget. Now i have a similar issue in FF: By using iframeTarget="#myIFrame" i have this:

in FF:

- first file uploaded
- redirct in the IFrame "#myIFrame"
- scirpt stoped (the following files are not uploaded)

in IE:

- first file uploaded
- redirect in the whole page (and the followoing fiels are not uploaded)

If i do not use the iframeTarget option, it works again with FF (all Files uploaded without any redirect).

Main issue: how to get it working in IE?

Side Issue: what's the difference for FF by using this option "iframeTarget"? (May be, this points to the solution for IE)

basic code:

```
    jQuery('#CreateFormUploadNew').submit(function() { 


    // submit the form 
    //jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit({
    //jQuery('#CreateFormUploadNew').ajaxForm({
    jQuery('#CreateFormUploadNew').ajaxSubmit({

        //iframe: false, //falls false, werden keine Files hochgeladen, true oder weglassen ....
        //clearForm: true, //nicht aktivieren, sonst fehlt der Name bei der suchen nach der ObjId
        //resetForm: true, //nicht aktivieren, sonst fehlt der Name bei der suchen nach der ObjId
        //dataType: 'script',
        iframeTarget: '#myIframe',
        beforeSubmit: function(a,f,o) {
            changeUploadValues(i)
            i++
        },
        success: function(data) {

            jQuery("#uploadFeedback").append("success started<br />");

            //...
            //some additional stuff like setting Meta Data
            //...

            if (i > 1) {
                changeUploadValues(i)
                jQuery('#CreateFormUploadNew').submit();
            }

        } //Success


    }); 
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 

    return false; //ajaxSubmit()
}); //submit
```

Thomas